# Read Serial Port After Writing using Node.js

Tags: node.js, serial-port

My node.js script uses the `serialport` npm package to read and write to `COM5` port, which is connected to an RS-232 device. This device only writes to the serial port when it receives a command sent by the PC connected to it.

How can I read what is returned by the RS-232 device after writing to it?

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var port = new SerialPort('COM5', {
    parser: SerialPort.parsers.readline('\r')
}, function() {
    port.write('#01RD\r', function(err) {
        if(err)
            console.log('Write error')
        else {
            // HOW TO READ RESPONSE FROM DEVICE?
        }
    });
    port.write('#01VER\r', function(err) {
        if(err)
            console.log('Write error')
        else {
            // HOW TO READ RESPONSE FROM DEVICE?
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a better way to do it. By function calling, 
first create your function of reading and writing:

```
var serialport = require("serialport");
var SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort;

var sp = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyACM0", {
  baudrate: 9600,
  parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\n")
});

function write() //for writing
{
    sp.on('data', function (data) 
    {
        sp.write("Write your data here");
    });
}

function read () // for reading
{
    sp.on('data', function(data)
    {
        console.log(data); 
    });
}

sp.on('open', function() 
{
    // execute your functions
    write(); 
    read(); 
});
```

Comment: I have a button on a UI that the user clicks on to initiate a serial write. How should I handle this read/write using an event driven approach?

Comment: I see, so we are doing the same thing. Im now in that part too. And they say we can use Express for this. Check my thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41647971/how-to-execute-node-function-using-html-button/

Comment: Your read/write function create a event emitter memory leak.