# How to execute node function using html button

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, node-serialport

I'm new at nodejs and I want to write to a serial port using node but now I want it to be triggered by a button. And the data is coming from a textbox.
My node script is doing fine when I run it in the console/terminal. But can't do it with a button in a webpage.
Here's my nodejs embedded in html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Node x HTML</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
    function write_serial() 
    {
        var serialport = require("serialport");
        var SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort;

        var sp = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyACM0", {
          baudrate: 9600,
          parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\n")
        });

            var text = document.getElementById("textbox1").value;

            sp.on('open', function() 
            {
                sp.on('data', function (data) 
                {
                    sp.write(name);
                });
            });
    }

    </script>

    <Input Type = "text" id = "textbox1" >
    <BR>
    <br><button onclick="write_serial();" href="javascript:;">Go!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the error I got when I open the console of the page (F12)

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Thanks in advance for your help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node.js is a hosting environment, that can execute JS and provides Node.js specific API. Browser, is a different hosting environment, with different API's. You can't use Node's specific API in a browser, and JS that uses Node API will result in an error in a browser.

For example, your script is using global `require` function, which is not available in a browser API's. And that's why:

> ReferenceError: require is not defined

Conversely, your script can't be executed on Node as well, since it uses browser API:

> document.getElementById("textbox1")

You've mixed API's from different environments in one script.

However, if your JS script doesn't use Node or browser specific API, it can be executed in both Node and a browser without an error. But it's not the case with your script.

The solution to your problem can be to split your script into two separate scripts, run one in a browser, and the other in Node.js, and to exchange data between them using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. 

In your last paragraph, did you mean that I need to open the console/terminal to run the NodeJS script(the node js script that I will separate from <script> tag )?

Comment: @Blanket, no, it's a bit more work than that. You'll have to setup a server that can listen for an http connections, [read this](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/)

Comment: Can I do that without installing another module like Express?  I actually want another device(that is also connected to the same network) to access the webpage. Is Express is the best solution for a beginner like me? What is the easier way? Thanks.

Comment: @Blanket, the article I linked shows how to setup a basic server without express

Comment: Hi, thanks. I accepted your answer for providing me an useful link. I will start learning first about http request. I think that might help. Thanks a lot for the effort. :)

Answer (score 1):

NodeJS is a non-browser JavaScript environment. You can't use most NodeJS features in a browser environment, because they aren't designed for it.

Instead, you'd have a local NodeJS process providing a web endpoint (e.g., a web server; perhaps using Express, but you don't have to) and run that NodeJS process so it's listening for web requests. Then you'd have a button on your web page that makes an ajax call to the NodeJS server, which performs the work.

Naturally, this would only allow you to perform the work on the machine where the server process is running.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.

I actually want another device(that is also connected to the same network) to access the webpage. Is Express is the best solution for a beginner like me?

Comment: @Blanket: Can't say "best" or not, but it's fairly simple to use and very frequently used for building web servers with NodeJS.

Comment: Hi, just to add some question, can you give me links of simple tutorials how to do this without express. All the links I saw is quite confusing for beginners like me. Advance thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe import the serialport module from https://wzrd.in/standalone/serialport@latest

In other hand, try to seperate the logic from the view, i don't know if your app will grow or if it's just a POC, but use a messageBroker or sockets to bind your actions'view with the engine ?

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. 

Did your link also means the http://www.npmjs.com/serialport

Comment: Hey :) yes same thing ! I don't like people who put -1 without any explications :(

Comment: i don't know bro im not the one who -1 you.